# View output of scalar value distributed on object in material editor

Tags: node-editor

When I want to edit a complex material and I want to know how, for example the specular looks like, is there a way to make its values visible without having to cut all the other stuff and connect it to the colour output?

There is a viewer node for images in the post compositing. Is there a similar way for materials?

Comment: Have you enabled Node Wrangler?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a render pass in the shading dropdown when using Cycles or Eevee (that is, in a rendered or material preview, but not in a solid, Workbench preview.)  Your options for the render pass depend on the renderer.

For viewing only the specular output of a material, you should choose "Specular Light" or "Glossy Direct" (although Glossy Direct doesn't take bounces into account.)

[image]

Here we can see, despite my pink objects, I'm only seeing the monochrome specular part of the Principled BSDF ouput.

If what you'd rather see is the literal color of the specular, without regard to lighting, you can set the Render Pass to Specular Color or Glossy Color.  There are a lot of other options there as well.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. I think I found another way, thats more what I had in mind. Connect the value you want to debug to an AOV output node and give the output a Name, for example "Debug". In the render settings under Passes > Shader AOV add a new AOV. Give it the same Name as your AOV output node. Then under Render Pass there is a new option "AOV", set it to this and you will be able to see how much of the value is applied on which point.
Maybe you could edit your answer and then I would accept it? Or should I write my own answer?

Comment: That's definitely a good idea!  You should write your own answer and mark it.